# How do I plot a histogram's image from Pyimagej?

Tags: python, histogram, imagej, pyimagej

```
# Create an ImageJ gateway with the newest available version of ImageJ.
import imagej
import pathlib
import numpy
ij = imagej.init()
# Load an image.
img_path = pathlib.Path('C:/Users/Bernardo/TCC/thyroid/1_1.jpg')
image = ij.io().open(str(img_path))
ij.py.show(image, cmap='gray')
```

I wanna plot a histogram using pyimagej, after reading this image.

Comment: Questions about pyimagej are best asked on the primary support channel, https://forum.image.sc

Answer (score 0):

well, you can just use matplotlib:

```py
# Create an ImageJ gateway with the newest available version of ImageJ.
import imagej
import pathlib
import numpy
ij = imagej.init()
# Load an image.
img_path = pathlib.Path('C:/Users/Bernardo/TCC/thyroid/1_1.jpg')
image = ij.io().open(str(img_path))
ij.py.show(image, cmap='gray')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(image.flatten())
```